# How to find strings using regular expressions in grep

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

So I have a file `list` with list of the people in a company. Each line contains Position(a short string), years, name(first and last), salary and nationality(three capital letters). They are divided with commas.

I want to find two things using grep and regex:

1. All people whose last name starts with C.
2. All people who have 3 names

For the first I have tried: `grep -E 'C\>' list`, but it gives back only one name(strange).
For the second: `grep "[[:alpha:]]\b[ ]\?[[:alpha:]]\b[]\?[[:alpha:]]" list`, but it also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\>` is the (zero length) regexp for the end of the word so `C\>` will probably not match last names that *start* with a 'C'. Maybe you should try `\<C` instead.

`[[:alpha:]]` matches *exactly one* character so this is also very unlikely to match a real name. You should append a multiplier like `*` or `+` (only in ERE?).